# HTML not working inside of Javascript function - Django

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django template that contains a Javascript function, like so:

```
<a class ="edit" href="{% url notecards.views.edit_notecard notecard.id %}"> Edit </a>
<h3 class="notecard"><p id="boldStuff">{{ notecard.notecard_name }}</p></h3>
<input id ="myButton" type="button" onclick="changeText()" value="View Answer"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    if (document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent == "{{ notecard.notecard_name }}")
      {
            document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent = "{{ notecard.notecard_html|safe }}";
            $("#myButton").prop("value", "View Question");
      }
    else
      {
            document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent = "{{ notecard.notecard_name }}";
            $("#myButton").prop("value", "View Answer");
      }
}
</script>
```

This script works perfectly when the variable values are not HTML. However, when they are HTML values, the function does not work at all. When clicking the button, nothing happens. In the console, I get:

`undetermined string literal` on the 4th line of the Javascript function, and I also get `changeText` is not defined on the 1st function declaration line.

My page source for the function looks like this for one of the values that is having an issue:

```
function changeText(){
    if (document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent == "Here is a question hey whats up?")
      {
            document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent = "<p>Here is an answer hey whats up. </p>
<p>Here is an answer hey whats up. Here is an answer hey whats up. </p>
<p>Here is an answer hey whats up.</p>
<p>Here is an answer hey whats up.Here is an answer hey whats up.vHere is an answer hey whats up. v</p>";
            $("#myButton").prop("value", "View Question");
      }
    else
      {
            document.getElementById("boldStuff").textContent = "Here is a question hey whats up?";
            $("#myButton").prop("value", "View Answer");
      }
}
```

The values can have

tags as shown, as well as list items, etc.

I have tried using both `.textContent` and `.innerHTML`, and the issue is the same.

Thank you

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support multi-line strings like that, you'll need to escape the embedded newlines. I'm no Django guru but there should be something in the template system that should properly escape text for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. This may be the newb in me talking, but if I escape the HTML through Django, then there would be no way for me to display the output in separate lines then correct?

New lines in the output are absolutely necessary here, so if that's the case I may have to remove the JS here.

Comment: There should be an "escape for JavaScript" function that would take care of the newlines (and embedded quotes and ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) template filter